# Beacon detection in iOS objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, beacon

I have a requirement of detecting all beacons without knowing their uuid. I have already implemented the code to detect a specific beacon and send a local notification to user. But I have no clue of how the beacons can be detected without knowing the uuid and that too this code should work in background, even if app is terminated. In android they use the estimote sdk,

```
 beaconManager.startMonitoring(new Region(“otherRegion”, null, null, null);
```

So it detects all the beacons without initializing uuid. Can similar thing be implemented in iOS? Kindly help...

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked with iBeacons but I don't think you CAN listen for any beacon, regardless of UUID. You can listen to any major/minor ID, but you have to specify the UUID.